# Detect audio levels from track on windows phone

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to detect the audio levels from a playing track using background agent or any other way?

What I'm trying to achieve is listen to the track, get a float and change colour based on the levels of the  audio being played.

How would you approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detect the decibels level of a sound recorded. Actually, in WP7 (I can't find for WP8, yet!) there is no APIs to get decibel level directly. But I can use microphone to get data to simulate decibel. The code like this:

```
......

microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);

........

 void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)

{


            double sum = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + 2)

            {

                double sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i) / 32768.0;

                sum += (sample * sample);

            }

            double rms = Math.Sqrt(sum / buffer.Length);

            decibel = 92.8 + 20 * Math.Log10(rms);


}
```

This is the source http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f04e0629-2609-4542-a141-46166f4cbdeb/how-to-get-the-decibel-with-c